# Single onChange for only one form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to ReactJs, So I'm trying to edit a `post` record from a POST rest api.

My `post` object looks like this.

**Response data**

```
post: {
        title: 'the title',
        body: 'the body'
}
```

**EditPost.js**

```
state = {
    post: {
        title: '',
        body: ''
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const { id } = this.props.match.params;
    jsonPlaceholder.get(`/posts/${id}`).then(res => {
        this.setState({ post: res.data })
        console.log(this.state.post)
    })
}

handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
}
```

And I bind it like so and assign the onChange

```
<input type="text" name="title" placeholder="This is the title" value={this.state.post.title} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} />

<textarea value={this.state.post.body} name="body" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)} ></textarea>
```

My problem is this is not updating the post from the state, its creating a new state.

**Example:**

From `state = { post: {} }` to `state = { post: {}, title: '', body: ''}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not accessing `post` correctly, `spread` the original object and change the `property` you want

```
handleChange = e => {
    this.setState(prevState =>({
        post:{
            ...prevState.post,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        }
    }));
}
```

Notice that I'm using the `updater` version of `setState`. It's safer to use a `snapshot` than actually `...this.state` cause you have no guarantees that the `state` isn't beeing changed somewhere else.

Comment: This answer is throwing me an error of property `name` of null. So I changed it back to `this.state.post`

Comment: Probably cause `post` wasn't declare. Still a good practice to use the `updater` version.

Comment: I added a `e.persist();` and now its working thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should add in your method ‘post’ property.

Like this:

```
this.setState({ post: { ...this.state.post, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } });
```

But I don’t recommend you to use nested prop to this.